# Não consigo fazer o redirecionamento para outra tela

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Tenho uma aplicação em React Native com a rota inicial apontando para a tela AuthLoadingScreen que verifica se o usuário tá logado e redireciona para Login ou Home, como o usuário não tá logado, o resultado esperado era que AuthLoadingScreen redirecionasse para a tela de Login, mas isso não acontece, a aplicação permanece em AuthLoadingScreen sem fazer o redirecionamento esperado.

**Auth Loading Screen**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
View, 
ActivityIndicator, 
StatusBar,
Dimensions
} from "react-native";

import {getToken} from '../../services/AuthService';
import styles from "./styles";
import {
NavigationParams,
NavigationScreenProp,
NavigationState,
} from 'react-navigation';

const width = Dimensions.get("screen").width;
interface Props {
    navigation: NavigationScreenProp<NavigationState, NavigationParams>;
 }

export default class Login extends Component<Props> {
   constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this._bootstrapAsync();
}

   _bootstrapAsync = async () => {
       const userToken = getToken();
       this.props.navigation.navigate(userToken ? 'Home' : 'Login');
   };

   render() {
      return(
          <View>
              <ActivityIndicator />
              <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
          </View>
      );
   }
}
```

**AuthService**

```
 import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

 export const setToken = (value: string) => AsyncStorage.setItem("TOKEN", value);

 export const removerToken = () =>  AsyncStorage.removeItem('token');

 export const getToken = async () => {
     return await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
 }
```

**Routes**

```
import {createStackNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';

import Login from './screens/login/Login';
import AuthLoadingScreen from './screens/login/AuthLoadingScreen';
import Home from './screens/home/Home';

export const LoginRoute = createStackNavigator({
    Login: {
       screen: Login,

       navigationOptions: {
           header: null
       }
     }
    });

export const HomeRoute = createStackNavigator({
    Login: {
       screen: Home,

       navigationOptions: {
          headerLeft: null
      }
 }
   });

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(
   createStackNavigator({
       AuthLoadingScreen: {
          screen: AuthLoadingScreen
       },

      LoginScreen: {
          screen: LoginRoute
      },

      HomeScreen: {
          screen: HomeRoute
      }  
   },

   {
      initialRouteName: 'AuthLoadingScreen',
   }
  ));

export default AppContainer;
```

Comment: Qual o motivo de se utilizar 3 stack navigator? apenas 1 não seria o bastante? Você pode usar um switch navigator como principal para fazer a troca do login screen para o home screen.

Comment: É, realmente não tem necessidade, depois corrijo no código

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com o seu código, a função "getToken" (do arquivo AuthService) faz a leitura do token. Você usou o async/await nesta função, mas, no seu arquivo "Auth Loading Screen", não usou o "await" para esperar pelo retorno (dentro da função "_bootstrapAsync"). Desta forma, o valor de token deve estar vazio, e o redirecionamento esperado não ocorre.

Ajuste a função para ficar da seguinte forma:

```js
_bootstrapAsync = async () => {
       const userToken = await getToken();
       this.props.navigation.navigate(userToken ? 'Home' : 'Login');
   };
```

Comment: Isso resolveu o meu problema, obrigada! Na implementação do getToken() tem o await, então achei que não precisaria repetir na chamada do método

Answer (score 2):

Voce não precisa da pagina **AuthLoadingScreen** para fazer o redirecionamento, você pode simplesmente fazer isso na pagina de login.

```
componentDidMount() {
   const logado = true;
   if (logado === true) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
   }
}
```

Se preferir pode colocar sua lógica de redirecionamento dentro da função **render** antes do **return**.

Comment: Interessante, vou mudar a minha implementação para usar dessa forma, obrigada!